# procurar dado em um json python

Tags: python

tenho o﻿ seguinte código

```
    with open('states.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
﻿
for state in data["jquery"]:
    if(argumentos[2] == state['version']):
        print(state['name'], state['version'] + "existe")
    else:﻿
        print("nao tem")﻿
```

ao executar o programa em python

```
python programa.py jquery 3.3.1
```

ele deve procurar no json onde esta escrito jquery e verificar se tem o segundo parâmetro que é a versão 3.3.1

só que no meu código acima ele percorre todo o json me dando a seguinte saida

```
jquery 3.3.1 existe
nao te﻿m
```

ele ta validando as 2 linhas,  se achar ele deve mostrar mensagem de sucesso caso contrario ele deve mostrar mensagem que não existe só que ele me mostra as 2 mensagem  porque no json o primeiro bloco é verdadeiro e o segundo é falso na saída final eu só quero que me mostre se existe o que eu estou procurando ou não.

meu json

```
{
"jquery":[
    {
        "name": "jquery",
        "version": "3.3.1",
        "extension": "js",
        "caminho": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    },
    {
        "name": "jquery",
        "version": "1.5.6",
        "extension": "js",
        "caminho": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.6.min.js"
    }
],

"bootstrap":[
    {
        "name": "bootstrap",
        "version": "1.2.8",
        "caminho": "https://bootstrap.com.br"
    }
]
}
```

se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda agradeço

Comment: Dica: Defina uma variável como False, faça a verificação e caso encontre o valor defina como True, depois você exibe o resultado com base no valor da variável, dá até para sair do laço caso encontre o valor

Comment: tentei fazer do jeito que você me falou mas provavelmente estou fazendo errado e  não to conseguindo ter o resultado que quero se você puder me dar um exemplo simples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz de uma forma bem parecida com a sua, a única diferença é a definição de uma variável para o controle

Ela é definida como `False`, caso encontre será definida para `True`, daí no final é só fazer a verificação, caso não ache o conteúdo procurado, a variável permanece com o valor padrão

```
with open('states.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

contem = False

for state in data["jquery"]:
    if (argumento[2] == state['version']):
        contem = True

if (contem):
    print(state['name'], state['version'] + "existe")
else:
    print("nao tem")
```

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo

Comment: voltei aqui encontrei um problema e não sei o que é ele ta sempre me retornando o mesmo valor exemplo se eu executar o script assim > python programa.py jquery 3.3.1 ele ta me retornando assim no console > jquery 1.5.6 existe. ou seja ele não ta me mostrando o que eu quero e sim o ultimo resultado do json tem alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: Obrigado pela dica consegui resolver o problema no resultado